# Tweepy to search and get a list of users from Twitter?

Tags: tweepy

Tweepy, I am trying to search for Twitter users who are special collections libraries in the United States. I am trying to use this:

import tweepy

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

users = api.search_users(q="special collections library"[per-page,20][page,0])

I seem to be getting "syntax error" because I can't figure out how to designate the per-page and the page.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Paste the full error. Also please format the code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to share a larger block of your exact code, as it's hard to necessarily see if your specific syntax error is occurring on the line you shared or somewhere else in the process.

I would suggest using the Code Sample tool and copy&pasting a larger slice.

Comment: Thanks! This is really the first line of code! Here you go: import tweepy

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

users = api.search_users(q="special collections library"[per-page,20][page,0])

Comment: I am a complete beginner here, first time using Python and Tweepy!

Comment: I would edit your original post to use the "Code Sample" button to make sure your code is readable, rather than putting it in the comments where we can't see whitespace etc.

Comment: If you're using python, whitespace is going to be VERY important, especially when it comes to syntax errors... Also make sure to upvote everything :D